# How to deal with session in php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, authentication, session-cookies

I'm fairly new to stockoverflow.com because I am I am looking for a while for an answer, I thought, I put my question here.
The base looks like this:

index.php:

```
<body>
<div id=”login”> This <div> is hidden
<div>my Login form</div>
</div>

<ul>
<li>menu item</li>
<li>menu item </li>
<li>…</li>
<li><a href=”#” class=”login”>login</a></li>

</ul>

rest of my code……

</body>
```

login-form is called in this way:
function.js

```
$('#login').hide();
$('.login').click(function() {
$('#login').show();
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; 
});
```

When I click on submit I can login with the following code:

login.js
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#message").hide();

$("#submit").click(function(){
$("#message").hide('normal');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'login.php',
data: $("#main form").serialize(),

success: function(data)
{
if (data === 'true') {

$(".login").fadeOut(500);
$('.login).html("<div class='loader'></div>")
.hide()
.fadeIn(2500, function() {
$('.login).load('administrator/test.php');
})

}
else {
$('#message').slideDown('slow');
}
}
});
return false;
});

});
```

And php code:
Login.php

```
try {
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = :email AND passenc = :pass' );
$stmt->execute(array(email => $email, 'pass' => $pass));

$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($count > 0) {
echo 'true';
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

} else {
echo "false";
}

}
```

Until here everything works fine, I can login and get admin page. Perhaps someone advice how to do it better.

But my question is this:

If I then close the loaded  or click F5 my index.php page reloads. There's nothing wrong with but here starts my problem.

If I then click login again then I get the login form displayed instead of the protected page when the session is created. How do I get it done when the session is created and I click the login button the page redirect to the protected page and if the session has expired login form is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check user , if already login then redirect , put this code at the first line of `login.php`

```
session_start();
$url = "your private page";
if ( isset($_SESSION['email']) )
{
   header("Location :$url");
   die();
}
```